# Protection of API against direct access

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have separate backend and frontend. However, they run on the same server (this may change in the future). The backend serves as an api and is powered by Laravel. Frontend by Nuxt (Vue).

I wish only my Nuxt application could access the api. How can I configure Laravel to only return data if the request comes from a Nuxt application?

I thought about adding a special token to requests, but the user will be able to check what request is coming out and capture the token. Can anyone give me ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: You can have a look at cors, for lavarel there is this package: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: @dreijntjens CORS does not stop anyone from accessing a URL directly, that is not what it is for

Answer (score 1):

You must be knowing about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). So in your Laravel Server, allow requests from only the frontend server's domain like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution would be to add [serverMiddleware](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/) in the nuxt project and route all the requests to the "real" api through it. Clients will hit the internal nuxt api and they will not be able to see the actual request made to the real api. There you can also add the token you are talking about for extra layer of security.

Comment: Could you please show some simple example? Because I don't really know how to use it